# My gmail address suddenly appears as a mount point on PCmanfm

Tags: 18.04, email, lxde, pcmanfm

To whom it may concern, there appears to be absolutely nothing on the Internet about this problem as searches turned out nothing relevant, but I have a link to my email adress (as a mount point) under "Places" and "Devices" on PCmanFM.  I didn't put it there, trying to open it yields "Invalid credentials for (email address)" and trying to delete the link yields "Operation not supported by back end".  IF it helps I did install the FFADO firewire adapter software (which I shoud uninstall as I have no firewire devices what-so-ever, I was foolishly hoping I could turn that port into another USB port and even wasted good nmoney on cords. That was a mistake well learned, the ports are incompatible and always will be).  I booted up today and suddenly this email link is on my pcmanfm, I can't log into it, and I can't remove it.  What to do (besides removing FFADO which I intend to do anyway)?

Don't say use Nautilus as my computer can't handle a full Gnome system, that's why I'm using LXDE.

I also tried using a root session (ironically using gksudo, maybe use sudo -i instead, but I think it'll yield the same result.  Just tried it and it did) and, both with gksudo and sudo -i, it didn't even show the mounted devices so I couldn't unlink it that way.  How to get rid of it, or make it work?

Version is Ubuntu 18.04 using LXDE (not Lubuntu, there are some Gnome features still on the machine, like gksudo and gedit).  It is a full OS, non-virtualized.  I installed back in 16.04 (later upgraded to 18.04) back when my only other choice for my machine was Windows 10, like heck I will allow THAT on my computer.

Comment: You're likely not using the lightest machine, as some of your choices will force two libraries in memory that do exactly the same thing (eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gedit) LXDE is GTK2 so the lightness of it is being lost by use of GTK3 apps, so using XFCE/Xubuntu may turn out lighter though it'll depend on your usage, though it still won't be as light as it could be. Have you looked in your `history` to see what you actually did; I suspect you did do it via copy/paste into a file you haven't mentioned. I really don't understand what you're describing though anyway

Comment: I use a similar configuration (Ubuntu with LXDE) so if you provide more information I can look into it.  For example a screen shot of pcmanfm (redact your email address), is there anything under /run/user/1000/gvfs/, etc.

Comment: ACtually, I think removing FFADO and Thunderbird, then rebooting worked for me anyway.  I just turned the computer on now, and it's not there anymore.  Also, maybe another apt update/apt upgrade may have fixed it too, probably an irreproducable bug.  Also, just checked the /run/user/1000/gvfs/ dfolder, is empty.  So whatever I did worked.  If it were stil there, I would have screenshotted it for you, but it's not so...solved, I think?  Also, I might give xubuntu a try, too. But I like LXDE too much to switch, but could strip some more of the GTK3 apps though, but that's a separate topic.

Comment: @KarlSpeth If you have solved this, then post an answer about how you solved it.  If the issue is just no longer relevant because it 'went away on its own' then we can close it.  Moderators don't have the ability to mark an answer as 'solved' in the way a forum would have that capacity, as Ask Ubuntu is not a *forum* site.